# gradle can't resolve dependency that is resolved by maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-publish

I published a package to gcloud artifact registry (gradle/maven-publish). I use this as a dependency in two projects (maven and gradle). The dependency is resolved by maven but gradle shows.

`Could not resolve com.company.group:art:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Also, I use another dependencies from the same repository and these are normally resolved. This means there can be no issues with access rights etc. Maybe I'm missing something when publishing the package. I can't figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the actual solution, but I just changed gradle version and it worked for me.

Comment: Do you have enabled auto-import? Maybe changing Gradle version reimported the whole project?

Comment: @milkamar yes, previously i tried everything : reimported dependencies, cleaned caches and reimported, but all these did not work out...